# unable to read the data of incoming request in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I am trying to create a sample login page using node,express and angularjs.

Below is my login view

```
<div class="loginpage">
<div class="loginpage_content">
    <div style="margin-top:30px;padding:10px;width:100%;text-align:center;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold">Please Enter Your Login Crendtials</div>
    <table width="80%" style="margin-top:40px;margin-left:50px;text-align:center;font-size:20px">
        <tr height="40px"><td width="25%">UserName</td><td width="5%">:</td><td width="70%"><input type="text" ng-model="name"></td></tr>
        <tr height="20px"></tr>                     
        <tr height="40px"><td width="25%">Password</td><td width="5%">:</td><td width="70%"><input type="password" ng-model="pass"></td></tr>
        <tr height="30px"></tr> 
        <tr height="40px"><td  colspan="3" style="align:left"><input type="button" value="Login" ng-click="login()"><input type="button" value="Clear" style="margin-left:10px"><a href="" style="margin-left:10px">Change Password</a></td></tr>   
    </table>
    <div style="margin-top:10px;padding:10px;width:99%;text-align:center;font-size:20px;Color:red;display:none">Enter valid Username & Password</div>   
</div>
```

controller for login page

```
angular.module("Fms").controller('LoginCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http)
{
$scope.results ="";
$scope.name ="";
$scope.pass ="";
$scope.login=function()
{
    $http(
    {   
        method: 'get',
        url: '/login',
        data:  'LOG CHECK',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    }).
    success(function(response) 
    {
        console.log("success"); // Getting Success Response in Callback
        console.log(response);
    }).
    error(function(response) 
    {

    });
}
  }]);
```

code for serving incoming request

```
  server.get('/login', function(req, res)
  {
         console.log(req.data);
        res.send("received");
  });
```

problem is i want to read the data passed via get request. I tried many things...

console.log(req.data); returns undefined why????

Comment: try read like `req.query.data`.

Comment: @Mritunjays i tried tat too.....

Comment: what are you getting. Some error or what

Comment: no error in console but  console.log(req.query.data); returns undefined and i even get the response for request

Comment: in `$http` data field should be an object try `data:{data:'LOG CHECK'}`, then you should be able to access through `req.query.data`.

Comment: sorry, I forgot for `get` request the field is `params` not `data`, `data` is used for post request. try changing `data:{data:'LOG CHECK'}` to `params:{data:'LOG CHECK'}`

Comment: i have one more doubt is this the right way to pass user name and password in request params :  {username:$scope.name,password:$scope.pass},

Comment: ya I think so, or if you want some protection use can use hash encryption-decryption for password like md5. But I've not used these things so I don't know properly

Comment: once again thanks for ur help. I will try that too....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

**1)** Angularjs `$http get` takes field as `params` to send the data with request. And params value should be an object.

So send request as bellow

```
$http(
{   
    method: 'get',
    url: '/login',
    params:  {data:'LOG CHECK'},
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
})
```

**2)** On server side read get data like `req.query.data` instead of `req.data`.